# pandas set boolean values for a column based on values of another column using regex match

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a `df` that one column (`acount_no`) contains empty strings, space strings and repeated digits strings as its values. For these values, I want to create a new column (`valid_account_no`) and set `False` to their corresponding rows. Also if length of any `account_no` are `<=` 4, they will be set `False` to `valid_account_no`. the `df` looks like,

```
 id    account_no    valid_account_no
 1                   False
 2     999999        False
 3     1234          False
 4     123456        True
```

this my code,

```
# sets boolean values of column valid account no when account no is spaced or repeated number
df['valid_account_no'] = df['account_no'].str.match(r"\b(\d)\1+\b| +")

# if length of any account nos are <= 4 or the account nos are empty
# set values of column valid account no to False
invalid_account_indices = df[(df['account_no'].str.len() <= 4) |
                             (df['account_no'] == '')].index
df.loc[invalid_account_indices, 'valid_account_no'] = False
```

I am wondering if there a better way to achieve this, in a sense to make it more concise and efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach itself if good, another work around is with simple boolean algebra i.e

```
m1 = df['account_no'].str.match(r"\b(\d)\1+\b| +")
m2 = df['account_no'].str.len()<=4
m3 = df['account_no'] == ''
df['valid_account_no'] = (m1) | (m2 & m3)
```

Comment: made a mistake in my OP, should use `(df['account_no'].str.len() <= 4) | (df['account_no'] == '')` instead of `&`